# How to show sales order field in the sales orderline by default using context in odoo 8.0?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have a field named sales_ship under sale.order model and another field named ship_sale in the sale.order.line. Now what I want is to have the selected sales_ship in the sales.order to come by default in the ship_sale in the  sale.order.line by default. How to do it by using context? Here is my full code.

**py**.

```python
from openerp import models , fields 


class ShipInfo (models.Model): 
    _name = "ship.ship"
    imo = fields.Char (string = "IMO" , size = 64 , required = True ) 
    hull_number = fields.Char (string = ' Hull Number ' , size = 64 , required = True ) 
    engine_number = fields.Char ( string = ' Engine Number ' , size = 64 , required = True ) 
    vessel_name = fields.Char ( string = 'Vessel Name' , size = 64 ) 
    build_year = fields.Char ( string = 'Build Year' , size = 64 ) 

    ship_yard = fields.Many2one ( 'res.partner' , string = 'Ship Yard') 
    ship_owner = fields.Many2one ( 'res.partner' , string = 'Ship Owner' ) 
    ship_management = fields.Many2one ( 'res.partner' ,string= 'Ship Management' ) 
    engine_builder = fields.Many2one ( 'res.partner' , string = 'Engine Builder' ) 
    _rec_name = 'vessel_name' 


class SaleOrderInherited (models.Model): 
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    sales_ship = fields.Many2one ( 'ship.ship' , string = 'Sales Ship' ) 

class SaleOrderLineInherited (models.Model):
 _inherit = 'sale.order.line'
 ship_sale = fields.Many2one ( 'ship.ship' , string = 'Sales Ship')
```

**.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
    <menuitem id="ship_module" name="ship" parent="base.menu_base_config" action="action_view_ship" sequence="30"/>
    <!--<menuitem id="ship_menu" name="ship information" parent="ship_module"/>-->
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="ship_form">
        <field name="name">ship.ship.form.view</field>
        <field name="model">ship.ship</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="ship info">
                    <sheet>
                    <group>
                       <group> <field name="imo"/>
                        <field name="hull_number"/>
                        <field name="engine_number"/>
                        <field name="vessel_name" context="{'sales_ship':sales_ship}"/>
                        <field name="build_year"/>
                       </group>
                        <group>
                        <field name="ship_yard"/>
                        <field name="ship_owner"/>
                        <field name="ship_management"/>
                        <field name="engine_builder"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
        </field>
    </record>

     <record model="ir.ui.view" id="ship_tree">
        <field name="name">ship.ship.tree</field>
        <field name="model">ship.ship</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="ship info">
                        <field name="imo"/>
                        <field name="hull_number"/>
                        <field name="engine_number"/>
                        <field name="vessel_name" context="{'sales_ship':sales_ship}"/>
                        <field name="build_year"/>
                        <field name="ship_yard"/>
                        <field name="ship_owner"/>
                        <field name="ship_management"/>
                        <field name="engine_builder"/>
                </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_view_ship">
        <field name="name">ship info</field>
        <field name="res_model">ship.ship</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        <field name="help" type="html">
            <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create new ship
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>


    <!--Inherit the sale order form view-->
    <record id="view_sale_order_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">sale.order.custom.form.inherited</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
           <field name="sales_ship" context="{'sales_ship':sales_ship}"/>
      </xpath>
         <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
                <field name="ship_sale" context="{'sales_ship':sales_ship}"/>
         </xpath>
          <group>
             <button string="Add to Order Line"/>
          </group>
     </field>
    </record>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <record id="view_sale_order_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">sale.order.custom.form.inherited</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
         <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after">
               <field name="sales_ship" />
          </xpath>                                                             
          <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="context">{'default_sales_ship':sales_ship}</attribute>
          </xpath>
          <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page/field[@name='order_line']/tree/field[@name='name']" position="after">
                <field name="ship_sale" />
          </xpath>
          <group>
              <button string="Add to Order Line"/>
          </group>
         </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: But it gives an error.Uncaught Error: NameError: name 'sales_ship' is not defined

Comment: <field name="ship_sale" context="{'default_ship_sale':sales_ship}"/>                                   
Removed 'context=' from the above line of code, as it was giving error. But still the code doesn't show sales_ship in sale.order.line by default.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. just updated that. but it should work. can you please update above sale.order view in your question.